# Running two android services in activity and getting data from both, which is then used in a method?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-service

I am creating an Android application whereby on the main activity I start two services running which in turn will pass a string value each to this activity. I have created a broadcast receiver to receive the data from each of the services. My problem is that I want to run a notification method which compares the two string values, after both values have been received. I have tried running this method after I start both services, however I keep getting a null pointer exception. I was wondering if there is anyway you can use one broadcast receiver to receive data from different services, as I could just run the method in the onReceive method if this was possible. Or is there any way I can solve this null pointer error.

Here is my onStart method and notification method of my main activity:

```
String currentWeather;
String tweet;

...

@Override
protected void onStart()
{

  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {

        currentWeather = intent.getStringExtra("weatherconditions");

     }
  };

  auroraReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
  {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
        tweet = intent.getStringExtra("latestTweet");
     }
  };

  IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
  intentFilter.addAction(WeatherService.BROADCAST);
  registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

  IntentFilter auroraFilter = new IntentFilter();
  intentFilter.addAction(AuroraService.MY_ACTION);
  registerReceiver(auroraReceiver, auroraFilter);

  Intent newService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WeatherService.class);
  startService(newService);

  Intent auroraService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AuroraService.class);
  startService(auroraService);

  sendAuroraNotification();

  super.onStart();
}

public void sendAuroraNotification()
{

  if ((currentWeather.equals("Clear")) && (tweet.contains("red alert") || tweet.contains("amber alert")))
  {
     Intent thisIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
     PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, thisIntent, 0);
     NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationicon)
             .setContentTitle("Aurora Borealis")
             .setContentText("You can now view the Aurora Borealis in your area.")
             .setContentIntent(pIntent);

     notif.notify(001, builder.build());
  } else
  {
     myText.setText("No Notification yet");
  }

}
```

The code to send the data in both my Service classes is simple and run in onStartCommand method:

```
Intent sendInfo = new Intent();
sendInfo.setAction(BROADCAST);
sendInfo.putExtra("my_key", theString);
sendBroadcast(sendInfo);
```

EDIT:

```
My logcat when error occurs:

07-25 13:19:17.671    9569-9569/com.example.Clear_Skies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.Clear_Skies, PID: 9569
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.Clear_Skies/com.example.Clear_Skies.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.Clear_Skies.MyActivity.sendAuroraNotification(MyActivity.java:166)
        at com.example.Clear_Skies.MyActivity.onStart(MyActivity.java:108)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1239)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5322)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2569)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
            
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 2:

I have changed my code to receive both strings from the same Broadcast Receiver in the OnReceive method and then call the sendAuroraNotification method after this. However I still get an error like so:

```
07-25 17:11:36.413    5860-5860/com.example.Clear_Skies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.Clear_Skies, PID: 5860
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=receive_data flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.Clear_Skies.MyActivity$1@423e5378
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:862)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.Clear_Skies.MyActivity.sendAuroraNotification(MyActivity.java:149)
            at com.example.Clear_Skies.MyActivity$1.onReceive(MyActivity.java:78)
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:848)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my updated code for onStart method:

```
@Override

   protected void onStart()
   {

      receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
      {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
         {

            String currentWeather = intent.getStringExtra("weatherconditions");
            String tweet = intent.getStringExtra("latestTweet");
            sendAuroraNotification(currentWeather);

         }
      };

      IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
      intentFilter.addAction(RECEIVE_DATA);
      registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

      Intent newService = new Intent(this, WeatherService.class);
      startService(newService);

      Intent auroraService = new Intent(this, AuroraService.class);
      startService(auroraService);

      super.onStart();
   }
```

The logcat is saying that the null pointer error occurs when the sendAuroraNotification method is called.

EDIT 3:

I have managed to solve the problem with the following changes:

onStart method:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(WeatherService.WEATHER_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(AuroraService.AURORA_ACTION);
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

OnReceive method of BroadcastReceiver:

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
     String action = intent.getAction();
     String tweet="",currentWeather="";

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(AuroraService.AURORA_ACTION))
    {
       tweet = intent.getStringExtra("latestTweet");
    }

    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(WeatherService.WEATHER_ACTION))
    {
       currentWeather = intent.getStringExtra("weatherconditions");
    }

       sendAuroraNotification(tweet,currentWeather);

 }
```

Comment: myText.setText("No Notification yet") is this in activity class or service class?

Comment: @IllegalArgument the setText is in the activity class, its mainly just for testing purposes at the moment

Comment: MyActivity.java:166 is `notif.notify(001, builder.build());` ? May be your forgot to init `notify` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is you want to check two strings which you get from two different services and compare them. If I'm not wrong  You can use a same broadcast receiver to do this. Use same broadcast to receive value from your services and  once you get both value you can call your method

```
sendAuroraNotification()
```

to process strings. Also check whether you have initialized notify object & textview object properly or not.

Comment: I have changed my code in order to do this. However I am still getting an error Please see above

Comment: Also, I tested to see if the data was being received by setting the values to textViews, which worked but one string is a few lines long and it kept disappearing after a couple seconds

Comment: Disappearing means???  Post your updated code and specify exactly on which line you are getting the error

Comment: I have now posted the updated code. Disappearing means that initially the String showed up for a couple of seconds on screen and then the textView would have no text at all.

Comment: You need to check whether you have both value before calling sendAuroraNotification () method

Comment: I have tried receiving only one value and it works fine. the problem is receiving the two values, the first one seems to be received and then when the second is received, the first is overwritten which is strange.  I think it is something to do with the intent filter code in onStart or the fact that I am using one receiver for two services?

Comment: I have got it working! I had to use getAction() method in onReceive and store result in a String. Then had to check with an if statement for both actions from the two services and get the data within the ifs. Posted code above! Thanks